# Координаты соседей

Tags: python

Для клетки с координатами (x, y) в таблице размером M × N выведите координаты ее соседей. Соседними называются клетки, имеющие общую сторону.
Даны натуральные числа M, N, x, y.
В выходной файл выведите пары координат соседей этой клетки в произвольном порядке.

Почему-то выдает 0 баллов, хотя подставлял числа, вроде ответы правильные.

```
M, N, x, y = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())

if M != 1 and N != 1:
    if x == 1 and y == 1:
        print(x + 1, y)
        print(x, y + 1)
    elif x == 1 and y == N:
        print(x + 1, y)
        print(x, y - 1)
    elif x == M and y == 1:
        print(x - 1, y)
        print(x, y + 1)
    elif x == M and y == N:
        print(x - 1, y)
        print(x, y - 1)
    elif x == 1:
        print(x + 1, y)
        print(x, y + 1)
        print(x, y - 1)
    elif x == M:
        print(x - 1, y)
        print(x, y + 1)
        print(x, y - 1)
    elif y == 1:
        print(x - 1, y)
        print(x, y + 1)
        print(x + 1, y)
    elif y == N:
        print(x - 1, y)
        print(x, y - 1)
        print(x + 1, y)
    else:
        print(x - 1, y)
        print(x + 1, y)
        print(x, y + 1)
        print(x, y - 1)

else:
    if M == 1 and N != 1:
        if y == 1:
            print(x, y + 1)
        elif y == N:
            print(x, y - 1)
        else:
            print(x, y + 1)
            print(x, y - 1)
    elif N == 1 and M != 1:
        if x == 1:
            print(x + 1, y)
        elif x == M:
            print(x - 1, y)
        else:
            print(x + 1, y)
            print(x - 1, y)
```

Comment: if x == 1  А почему вы думаете, что М не 1

Comment: Понял, поправлю.

Comment: но, вообще, очень некрасиво

Comment: Есть пример входных данных и того, что должно получиться?

Comment: @splash58 Согласен, но как по другому?

Comment: @whizz169 входные данные
3 3
2 2
выходные данные
2 1
1 2
2 3
3 2

Comment: ща поправлю ответ

Comment: @splash58 исправил, но не помогло

Comment: вот, посмотрите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M, N, x, y = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())

if N > 1:
    if y == 1:
        print(x, y + 1)
    elif y == N:
        print(x, y - 1)
    else:
        print(x, y - 1)
        print(x, y + 1)
if M > 1:
    if x == 1:
        print(x + 1, y)
    elif x == M:
        print(x - 1, y)
    else:
        print(x - 1, y)
        print(x + 1, y)
```

На ваших входных:

```
N: 3
M: 3
x: 2
y: 2
...
2 1
2 3
1 2
3 2
```

Comment: К сожалению все равно 0 выдает.

Answer (score 1):

может, как-то так. Сделаем лист с набором изменения координат. И выведем те, которые не вышли за пределы матрицы

```
M, N, x, y =  3, 3 ,2, 2 # 2 1 1 2 2 3 3 2
for i,j in [(0,-1),(-1,0),(0,1),(1,0)]:
        if 1<=x+i<M+1 and 1<=y+j<N+1:
            print (x+i, y+j)
```

---

Давайте тогда мой цикл вскроем и превратим в линейную запись

```
if 1<=x<M+1 and 1<=y-1<N+1:
   print (x, y-1)
if 1<=x-1<M+1 and 1<=y<N+1:
   print (x-1, y)
if 1<=x<M+1 and 1<=y+1<N+1:
   print (x, y+1)
if 1<=x-1<M+1 and 1<=y+j<N+1:
   print (x+1, y)
```

Comment: Не понимаю. И задача в теме Условный оператор ,который идет перед циклами, т.е. предполагается решение без циклов.

Comment: ну, оставьте по вашему, я же не настаиваю :)

Comment: Ну я хочу узнать в чем проблема моего решения(не считая того, что оно ужасно на вид), почему мне за него дают 0 баллов.

Comment: а вы можете например посмотреть, что дадут за мое, но не засчитывать? :) А то как вам помогать, может, я тоже не понимаю :))

Comment: Могу конечно, ваше решение это начиная с for...?

Comment: ага, перед этим ввод оставьте

Comment: 0... Почему-то везде пишет не Неправильный ответ, а Ошибка во время выполнения программы.

Comment: а ввод у вас так, как написано в вопросе?

Comment: Ну да. Вот ссылка на задачу https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=276&chapterid=1445#1

Comment: а не заданы ли все эти числа в одной строке? может, надо их сплитом получать?

Comment: Вряд ли, там перед каждым модулем всю необходимую теорию дают. И в ней сплита нет. Но я сейчас попробую.

Comment: а вы видите, что программа печатает? просто первый инпут отправьте на печать до преобразования в инт

Comment: Нет, там выводится только количество баллов.

Comment: если там не одно число в строке, то прога упадет на преобразовании в инт

Comment: Ну да, и что делать?

Comment: как-то и не очевидно, опираясь на ограниченный набор знаний учеников. так можно пробовать  `M, N, x, y = input().split()`  и потом в инт перевести

Comment: А как потом в отдельные числа перевести?

Comment: так они сразу и получат значения

Comment: M=int(M) ; N= int(M) и тд

Comment: Спасибо!! Помогло, 100 баллов.

Comment: а мой код? Кстати, я вам там написал, как без цикла коротко сделать

Comment: Ваш тоже 100. Если через сплит

Comment: ага. отлично  :)